# Given a line and a point, how do you calculate the point on the line that is exactly 45 degrees?

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

Given a line connected by two points, (x1, y1) & (x2, y2).

And given a point not on the line, (x3, y3).

How do you calculate the point on the line that creates a line at a 45 degree angle. We'll call this point (x4, y4).

[image: Picture Representation Here.]

Thank you!

EDIT: *Question from the comments

[If the (x3, y3) point is "far" from the line-segment created by (x1,y1), (x2,y2). It wouldn't be possible to create a 45 degree angle like describe in this picture. How can I check for this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHnrp.png)

Comment: It doesn't have to be far: if point 3 is say to the right of point 2 and just above the line joining point 1 and point 2,  the intersections with the perpendicular and both of the 45-degree lines *could* be outside the segment. But once you find the coordinates of point 4, all you have to do is check whether $x_4$ is in the range $[x_1, x_2]$ *and* $y_4$ is in the range $[y_1, y_2]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it, could be a more elegant way:

First, we find the equation of a line through points $(x_{1},y_{1})$ and $(x_{2},y_{2})$. After that, we find the line through the point $(x_{3},y_{3})$ which is perpendicular to the line through points $(x_{1},y_{1})$ and $(x_{2},y_{2})$. After we do that, we find the intersecting point of those two lines, lets call it point $(x_{5},y_{5})$. Now we have one leg of the right triangle. We find the length of that leg, and we know that the angle being 45 degrees, both legs are the same length. Now we just add that length of the leg to the point $(x_{5},y_{5})$, and solve for point $(x_{4},y_{4})$. You will get two points by doing this.

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: Nice. I understand what you mean, but still have a few questions.

Comment: Just ask! Thank you for accepting my answer.

Comment: Bah, I was going to write my questions above, but I guess enter adds the comments. lol.

Anyways, How would I go about checking if it's unable to create a 45 degree angle? I'm thinking maybe you compare the lengths and check from there?

Comment: Given the conditions from your question above, it is $always$ able to create an angle between 0 and 90 degrees. At 0 degrees, lines would be parallel. 

You can do the procedure above for any angle in the interval (0,90). By having a one leg, you can get the length of the other one by trigonometry. 

Draw yourself an image of your problem. Put some point on the line that makes an angle $a$ with your first line. You will get that length of your other leg (lets call it $b$, and your first leg is $a$) is $$b = \frac{d}{\tan(a)}.

Comment: I think he means that $(x_4, y_4)$ might not be in the line *segment* between $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$.

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking about what @Nick said, but the informative given is also great to know. Thanks!

Comment: @Nick For it to make a perpendicular line, it doesn't have to be between those two. 

For it in being "in the line segment between $(x_{1},y_{1})$ and $(x_{2},y_{2}$", you just check if the $x_{3}$ is between $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ $OR$ $y_{3}$ is between $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$.

Hope that I understood your question correctly. Cheers!

Comment: Not true: take the two endpoints to be $(0, 0)$ and $(2, 2)$ and the off-the-line point to be $(1, 1000)$. $x_3$ is between $x_1$ and $x_2$ but the perpendicular does not cut the line segment - the intersection is off to the upper right somewhere.  In any case, I was trying to get into the OP's head so to speak, but maybe my interjection is not helpful at all.

Comment: @Nick Sorry, didn't understand the question, what the "line segment" actually was. If you want to check if the perpendicular line "cuts" between point p1=
(x1,y1) and p2= (x2,y2), just check if the distance from p1 to p5 (you get p5 by intersecting lines) and p2 to p4 is $less$ than distance from p1 to p2. 

I marked the points with p1, p2, etc. because I am not in the mood to write so many brackets. 

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: From p2 to p5* Mistake above, not p2 to p4!

Comment: Sorry I'm not very good at explaining with words, so I put an image in the main question to visualize my question.

Comment: No need to compute lengths to test for the solutions being on the line segment. A simple range check of the coordinates will do.

Answer (score 1):

The following is fundamentally the same as [Shocky2’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2332919/265466), but uses homogeneous coordinates to crank out the solutions via a direct computation.

Let the three given points be called, respectively, $P_1$, $P_2$ and $P_3$, and let $O$ be the intersection of the line $\overline{P_1P_2}$ with its perpendicular through $P_3$. The two lines through $P_3$ that make a 45° angle with $\overline{P_1P_2}$ intersect it at points that are the same distance from $O$ as is $P_3$, namely, the perpendicular distance from $P_3$ to $\overline{P_1P_2}$.

We have, in homogeneous coordinates, $P_1\sim[x_1,y_1,1]$, $P_2\sim[x_2,y_2,1]$ and $P_3\sim[x_3,y_3,1]$. The line $\overline{P_1P_2}$ is given by the cross product $\mathscr L\sim P_1\times P_2$. We then have $$|\mathscr L\cdot P_3|=d\|P_2-P_1\|\tag1$$ where $d$ is the distance from $P_3$ to $\overline{P_1P_2}$. (The two sides of this equation are twice the area of $\triangle{P_1P_2P_3}$ computed in different ways.) This means that the two 45° points are $$P\sim O\pm{\mathscr L\cdot P_3\over\|P_2-P_1\|}{P_2-P_1\over\|P_2-P_1\|}=O\pm{(P_1\times P_2)\cdot P_3\over(P_2-P_1)\cdot(P_2-P_1)}(P_2-P_1).\tag2$$

The starting point $O$ can be computed in a couple of ways. One is to use the fact that it’s the orthogonal projection of $P_3$ onto $\overline{P_1P_2}$, from which we have $$O\sim P_3-{\mathscr L\cdot P_3\over(P_2-P_1)\cdot(P_2-P_1)}N\tag3$$ where $N$ is obtained from $\mathscr L$ by setting its last component to zero. This is convenient because it shares a coefficient with (2), so we can combine the two formulas to obtain $$P\sim P_3-{(P_1\times P_2)\cdot P_3\over(P_2-P_1)\cdot(P_2-P_1)}(N \pm (P_2-P_1)). \tag4$$ Usually one must now divide through by the third component to convert from homogeneous to Cartesian coordinates, but since the last component of $P_3$ is $1$ and those of $P_2-P_1$ and $N$ are zero, we can drop them everywhere except the scalar triple product in the numerator of (4) and produce Cartesian coordinates directly.

The only thing left to do is to see which, if any, of these points actually lies on the line segment $P_1P_2$, but that’s a simple matter of checking that their coordinates fall between those of the endpoints $P_1$ and $P_2$.